# Use sklearn TfidfVectorizer with already tokenized inputs?

Tags: scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I have a list of tokenized sentences and would like to fit a tfidf Vectorizer. I tried the following:

```
tokenized_list_of_sentences = [['this', 'is', 'one'], ['this', 'is', 'another']]

def identity_tokenizer(text):
  return text

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=identity_tokenizer, stop_words='english')    
tfidf.fit_transform(tokenized_list_of_sentences)
```

which errors out as

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

is there a way to do this? I have a billion sentences and do not want to tokenize them again. They are tokenized before for another stage before this.

Comment: To be able to help, please add the full error message and add the minimum code required to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try initializing the `TfidfVectorizer` object with the parameter `lowercase=False` (assuming this is actually desired as you've lowercased your tokens in previous stages).

```py
tokenized_list_of_sentences = [['this', 'is', 'one', 'basketball'], ['this', 'is', 'a', 'football']]

def identity_tokenizer(text):
    return text

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=identity_tokenizer, stop_words='english', lowercase=False)    
tfidf.fit_transform(tokenized_list_of_sentences)
```

Note that I changed the sentences as they apparently only contained stop words which caused another error due to an empty vocabulary.

Comment: Any idea on how can I save and load the TfidfVectorizer object? If I'm using an external function such as the one in this example? I'm getting errors while trying to load it.

Answer (score 2):

The comments above make perfect sense, but the hardest part comes when you start trying serializing and de-serializing the model. The solution proposed by [@pmlk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8991007/pmlk) will give you an error if you would serialize the model as `joblib.dump(tfidf, 'tfidf.joblib')`:

```
tfidf = joblib.load('tfidf.joblib')

    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-9093b9496059> in <module>()
    ----> 1 tfidf = load('tfidf.joblib')
    <...>
    AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'identity_tokenizer'
```

So as [@Jarad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577947/jarad) mentioned, its better to use the lambda function as a tokenizer and a preprocessor. Lambdas can be serialized using `dill` (not with standard `pickle`/`joblib` though):

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x,
                        preprocessor=lambda x: x, stop_words='english')
tfidf.fit_transform(tokenized_sentences)
with open('tfidf.dill', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(tfidf, f)
```

And then you can load the model without any issues:

```
with open('tfidf.dill', 'rb') as f:
    q = dill.load(f)
```

In most cases, it is safer to [serialize only the vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69814443/save-tfidf-vocab-and-transformation-and-use-on-new-dataset/72663063#72663063) rather than the whole model - but if you for certain reasons can not do it (like me), the usage of lambdas and `dill` might be the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try [`preprocessor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) instead of `tokenizer`.

```
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

If `x` in the above error message is a list, then doing `x.lower()` to a list will throw the error.

Your two examples are all stopwords so to make this example return something, throw in a few random words. Here's an example:

```
tokenized_sentences = [['this', 'is', 'one', 'cat', 'or', 'dog'],
                       ['this', 'is', 'another', 'dog']]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=' '.join, stop_words='english')
tfidf.fit_transform(tokenized_sentences)
```

Returns:

```
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Features:

```
>>> tfidf.get_feature_names()
['cat', 'dog']
```

---

**UPDATE**: maybe use `lambda`s on tokenizer and preprocessor?

```
tokenized_sentences = [['this', 'is', 'one', 'cat', 'or', 'dog'],
                       ['this', 'is', 'another', 'dog']]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x,
                        preprocessor=lambda x: x, stop_words='english')
tfidf.fit_transform(tokenized_sentences)

<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> tfidf.get_feature_names()
['cat', 'dog']
```

Comment: This retokenizes the input that the preprocessor joined. I dont want to spend resources retokenizing again.

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Jarad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577947/jarad) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48675175/623735) just use a "passthrough" function for your analyzer but it needs to ignore stopwords. You can get stop words from `sklearn`:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
```

or from `nltk`:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('stopwords')
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

or combine both sets:

```
stop_words = stop_words.union(ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS)
```

But then your examples contain only stop words (because all your words are in the `sklearn.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS` set).

Noetheless @Jarad's examples work:

```
>>> tokenized_list_of_sentences =  [
...     ['this', 'is', 'one', 'cat', 'or', 'dog'],
...     ['this', 'is', 'another', 'dog']]
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x:[w for w in x if w not in stop_words])
>>> tfidf_vectors = tfidf.fit_transform(tokenized_list_of_sentences)
```

I like `pd.DataFrame`s for browsing TF-IDF vectors:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(tfidf_vectors.todense(), columns=tfidf.vocabulary_)
        cat       dog 
0  0.814802  0.579739
1  0.000000  1.000000
```